# Why does Wordpress loop output full posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

The following code outputs a listing of post titles.  Below this list, it also outputs each full post matching the tag "test" that is in category 8.  Why does it output full posts?  How do I prevent that?

```
$query_str = "cat=8&tag=test";
query_posts($query_str);

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   echo '<div><a href="';
    the_permalink();
    echo '">';
    the_title();
    echo '</a></div>';
endwhile;
```

Comment: do you mean its outputting `the_content` as well?

Comment: Yes, but without titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for size instead of using `query_posts` which is faulty use `WP_Query` like so

```
$args = array('cat' => 8, 'tag' => 'test');

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
$the_query->the_post();
echo '<div><a href="'. get_permalink($the_query->post->ID).'"/>' . get_the_title() . '</a></div>';
endwhile;


wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: That breaks the page.  Get an all white page.